# Is it possible to change the name of a variable at the declaration stage?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, variables

I have a vector with 10 elements, which contain the names of the
respectivepanels. Since I do not want to repeat the command for 10
times. There is a system to do this with only one statement. How do
you normally do:

```
Dim Test As New Panel 
Test.size = new point (10.10)
Test.location = new point (10.10) me.controls.add (test)
```

example:

```
Dim Test(n) As New Panel 
Test(n) .size = new point (10.10) 
Test(n).location = new point (10.10) 
me.controls.add (test (n))
```

Comment: It's not too clear what you want. Do you want to use the same variable for all 10 elements or want to change the name of the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array containing the names is called "vector", and that it is already populated with 10 items, this would do it:

```
For n as Integer = 0 to 9
    Me.Controls.Add(new Panel() With {.Name = vector(n), .Size = New Point(10, 10), .Location=New Point(10,10)})
Next
```

Then you can interact with it in several ways:

```
'if you know the actual name:
Dim pnlMyPanel as Panel = DirectCast(Me.Controls("pnlFirstPanel"), Panel)

'if you know the index in the vector containing the name:
Dim pnlMyOtherPanel as Panel = DirectCast(Me.Controls(vector(1)), Panel)

'Interact with it as you would any control:
pnlMyPanel.Visible = True
pnlMyPanel.Top = 100
```

Comment: Hi, If you wanted to interact with the panels created, such as clicking a message or an event?

Comment: @SalvatoreRaccardi I updated the answer I provided to show a couple of ways you could interact with the panel after adding it.